# Movement very fast

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a monogame project, where I want to move the player based on the the keyboard input. But my code just makes the movement super fast.

I tried around with different speed limits and checked if it might work if with different `GameTime` properties.

Where is the problem with my code?

```
public class Map {

    private Map() {
        Position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public string[][] MapData { get; set; }

    public ContentManager Content { get; set; }

    public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch { get; set; }

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    private Vector2 ArrayPosition;

    private readonly int Speed_X = 40;
    private readonly int Speed_Y = 32;

    public static Map Parse(string path) {
        var map = new Map();
        var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(Path.Combine("Content", path));
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            map.Data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var lines = map.Data.Split(new string[1] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var mapHeight = lines.Count();
        map.MapData = new string[mapHeight][];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) {
            var elements = lines[i].Split(';');
            map.MapData[i] = elements;
        }
        return map;
    }

    public void DrawMap(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager content, GameTime gametime) {
        this.SpriteBatch = spriteBatch;
        this.Content = content;
        for (int y = 0; y < MapData.Count(); y++) {
            var current = MapData[y];
            for (int x = 0; x < current.Count(); x++) {
                switch (current[x]) {
                    case "e":
                        drawEnemy(x, y);
                        break;

                    case "P":
                    case ".":
                        drawTile(x, y);
                        break;

                    case "w":
                        drawWall(x, y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        drawPlayer();
    }

    public void Move(Direction pdirection, GameTime gametime) {
        var direction = Vector2.Zero;
        var speed = Vector2.Zero;
        var y = Math.Floor(this.ArrayPosition.Y);
        var x = Math.Floor(this.ArrayPosition.X);
        switch (pdirection) {
            case Direction.Up:
                if (y > 0 && y < 16) {
                    direction = new Vector2(0, -1);
                    speed.Y = Speed_Y;
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Down:
                if (y < 16 && y >= 0) {
                    direction = new Vector2(0, 1);
                    speed.Y = Speed_Y;
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Left:
                if (x > 0 && x < 16) {
                    direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
                    speed.X = Speed_X;
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Right:
                if (x < 16 && x >= 0) {
                    direction = new Vector2(1, 0);
                    speed.X = Speed_X;
                }
                break;
        }
        ArrayPosition = (this.Position + (direction * speed)) / new Vector2(Speed_X, Speed_Y);
        var newPosition = this.Position + (direction * speed * gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds);
        if (this.MapData[(int)Math.Floor(ArrayPosition.Y)][(int)Math.Floor(ArrayPosition.X)] != "w") {
            this.Position = newPosition;
        }
    }

    private void drawPlayer() {
        var x = Position.X;
        var y = Position.Y;
        drawTile((int)x, (int)y);
        var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/player");
        this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
    }

    private void drawEnemy(int x, int y) {
        drawTile(x, y);
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/enemy"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawTile(int x, int y) {
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/grass"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawWall(int x, int y) {
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/wall"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawTexture(Texture2D texture, int x, int y) {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(x * 40, y * 32, 40, 32);
        this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: withouth using `ElapsedGameTime` your update (in perfect condition) is executed 60 times per second and that is `60 x speed` ... (or less depend of FPS because of complexity of code)

Comment: @DavorMlinaric OP _is_ using `ElapsedGameTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `TotalSeconds` property instead of `Milliseconds` in `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime`.  The latter is an `int` which is not useful for fractional computations whereas the former is a `double` which is.  Due to it being an `int` it also explains why your movement is very fast.

In your **Move()** method change this line:

```
var newPosition = this.Position + 
                  (direction * speed * 
                   gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds);
```

...to:

```
var newPosition = this.Position + 
                  (direction * speed * 
                   gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
```

However contrary to what the other poster says, **it is not necessary to perform a** `deltatime=0;` because `ElapsedGameTime` is defined as:

> The amount of elapsed game time since the **last update** - *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx)*

You don't want to go **resetting time intervals** as they will just lead to  animation which is **not** particularly **smooth**.

### Tell me more

- [Your First Game - XNA Game Studio in 2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx)

Comment: My problem now is, I want the character to move in 40x32 rectangles, like in Pokémon... And that doesn't help much :(

Comment: @Knerd It _still_ applies. You need to make your update a function of time

Comment: But how can I make it move like in Pokémon in Rectangles? The current version I have doesn't work...

Comment: @Knerd Moving in rectangles is a **new** question.  Moving them as a function of time irrespective of whether they are _meant to move fast or slow_ is covered on this page.

Comment: Ok, then I will ask it new. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Knerd You are very welcome.  I will look out for your new question and help you if I can. :)

Comment: To make it easy for you, here is my question. I hope you have an answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808334/

Answer (score 0):

use something like this in function **Move**:

```
float deltatime=0;
 public void Move(Direction pdirection, GameTime gametime) {
  deltaTime= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
  //calculate your object position using deltatime

 }
```

Comment: _"you must **give deltatime** value **zero** at the end of function because deltatime is **increasing continuesly**"_ - Incorrect.