# Move sprite like in Pokémon

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a game, where I want my characters to move in my field square by square, like in Pokémon.

With the code I have, it is moving square by square just it skips on every key hit about 4-5 squares. And just jumps around.

Can someone help me to get my code work in a similar manner like Pokémon?

The code I have is as follows.

```
public class Map {

    private Map() {
        Position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public string[][] MapData { get; set; }

    public ContentManager Content { get; set; }

    public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch { get; set; }

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

    private Vector2 ArrayPosition;

    private readonly Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(40, 32);

    public static Map Parse(string path) {
        var map = new Map();
        var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(Path.Combine("Content", path));
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            map.Data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var lines = map.Data.Split(new string[1] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var mapHeight = lines.Count();
        map.MapData = new string[mapHeight][];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) {
            var elements = lines[i].Split(';');
            map.MapData[i] = elements;
        }
        return map;
    }

    public void DrawMap(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, ContentManager content, GameTime gametime) {
        this.SpriteBatch = spriteBatch;
        this.Content = content;
        for (int y = 0; y < MapData.Count(); y++) {
            var current = MapData[y];
            for (int x = 0; x < current.Count(); x++) {
                switch (current[x]) {
                    case "e":
                        drawEnemy(x, y);
                        break;

                    case "P":
                    case ".":
                        drawTile(x, y);
                        break;

                    case "w":
                        drawWall(x, y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        drawPlayer();
    }

    public void Move(Direction pdirection, GameTime gametime) {
        var direction = Vector2.Zero;
        var x = this.ArrayPosition.X;
        var y = this.ArrayPosition.Y;
        switch (pdirection) {
            case Direction.Up:
                if (y > 0 && y < 16) {
                    direction = new Vector2(0, -1);
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Down:
                if (y < 16 && y >= 0) {
                    direction = new Vector2(0, 1);
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Left:
                if (x > 0 && x < 16) {
                    direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
                }
                break;

            case Direction.Right:
                if (x < 16 && x >= 0) {
                    direction = new Vector2(1, 0);
                }
                break;
        }
        Position += direction * Speed;
    }

    private void drawPlayer() {
        var tile = Position / Speed;
        var x = tile.X;
        var y = tile.Y;
        drawTile((int)x, (int)y);
        var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/player");
        this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, Color.White);
    }

    private void drawEnemy(int x, int y) {
        drawTile(x, y);
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/enemy"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawTile(int x, int y) {
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/grass"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawWall(int x, int y) {
        drawTexture(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tiles/wall"), x, y);
    }

    private void drawTexture(Texture2D texture, int x, int y) {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(x * 40, y * 32, 40, 32);
        this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Performance tip:**  Move all the `Content.Load<>` from your `Drawxxx(...)` to `LoadContent(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are using a mix of co-ordinate systems to represent things on your map in addition to possible cumulative movement delta error.  Consider having **one** co-ordinate system.  I'm not sure how big your map is so lets assume it's 10x10.  Therefore tiles; enemys; and the player's co-ordinates should be within {0...9}x{0...9}.

e.g. In your `DrawMap()` I see your tiles use a co-ordinate system of 0 to the dimensions of your `string[][] MapData`.  You leave scaling the co-ordinates until your `drawTexture()` as below which I think is a good idea:

```
private void drawTexture(Texture2D texture, int x, int y) {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(x * 40, y * 32, 40, 32);
    this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
}
```

---

**Tip:**  Try to avoid having *magic numbers* in your code.  Consider either defining 40 and 32 as constants or even better determine the tile size at runtime during `LoadContent()`.

---

However, your method `Move()`, which moves the player about based on `direction` is scaled by `Speed` defined below as:

```
private readonly Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(40, 32);
```

...which I don't think is a good idea because you are scaling the size of tiles with the player's speed which results in the player's co-ordinates being in an entirely different co-ordinate system than enemy's, walls and other map data.  Because it is scaled, you need to divide by the tile size all the time to normalise the player's co-ordinates whenever you wish to interact with the map.

Later when you draw the player you have this unusual line:

```
private void drawPlayer() {
    var tile = Position / Speed;
```

If `p` is position, `v` is velocity; `t` is time; then `p = vt` which follows that `t = p / v` so just reading the above line on its own is a little odd.  But I know what you are trying to do - determine the co-ordinates of the tile based on tile size.

However if you just normalise the player's position to always be with the range {0...MapData dimensions} without scaling by (40, 32) it would make things simpler.

### Changes

In your `Move()` method change this line:

```
    Position += direction * Speed;
```

...to:

```
    Position += direction;
```

Then change `drawPlayer()` from:

```
private void drawPlayer() {
    var tile = Position / Speed;
    var x = tile.X;
    var y = tile.Y;
    drawTile((int)x, (int)y);
    var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/player");
    this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, Color.White);
}
```

...to:

```
private void drawPlayer() {
    drawTile((int)Position.x, (int)Position.y);
    var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/player");

    var p = Position * new Vector2 (40,32);
    this.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, p, Color.White);
}
```

### Performance tip

- Move all the `Content.Load<>` from your `Drawxxx(...)` to `LoadContent(...)`.  Generally you want to minimize the loading of resources (particularly the same resources) during your game loop unless your game is streaming (which you are not in this case).

Comment: Works perfect :) Just the keys are super sensitiv and so the movement is super fast. Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: @Knerd How about a tick for this one? :)

Comment: Yeah, but I have the fast movement problem again. Do you have a solution that solves both? :)

Comment: @Knerd Sure thing.  You need to keep track of current vs last `KeyboardState`.  Only move when you know key has _just been pressed_ rather than _is key down_.  [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later. The tick is earned :) Thanks again :)